# Can we remove the fft tag from this question?

Tags: discussion

A user has suggested to add the tags [fft](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fft) and [signal-analysis](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/signal-analysis) to this question:

[Calculating the power of a signal](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/20507/calculating-the-power-of-a-signal)

However, I think the question has nothing to do with FFT. I could remove the tag but two experienced users have approved its addition. Did I overlook something?

Comment: Done!  Not sure why it was tagged `fft` at all.